# Implement __eq__ for a module

Tags: python

I see that a module can be compared to other objects with the standard `==` and `!=` operators.

Is it possible to override the “rich comparison” methods `__eq__` and `__ne__` of a module to customize their comparison? I am specifically looking to have the module resolve itself to a `tuple` defined within itself during the comparison in these methods.

I tried, eg for module `m`, adding the line `__eq__ = lambda other: other == m.my_tuple` in the desired module, but it does not work.

Comment: Huh? Modules don't have methods; that's only classes. Please show enough code that we can reproduce what you tried, see how it didn't work, and adjust it until it does. ([mre] guidelines apply -- a sample should be the _shortest possible code_ that can be run _without changes_ to see the same problem).

Comment: For `==` to work, the `__eq__` method would have to be defined on the class, not the object: `ModuleType`. Then you'd have to monkey-patch the import system to return objects of your type

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Modules clearly do have some methods, though it's not trivial to change them

Comment: ...this might be a place where using a mixin across all classes in your module is what you want, though it's hard to tell from what's given here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, fair enough; perhaps I should have specified _user-defined_ methods.

Comment: I am not sure where would you like to even use such functionality 
https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/singleton/
Basically every module in python is by default singleton and every singleton never should be eqal to anything else

Comment: if `==` isn't defined by `a` in the order `a, b`, the interpreter will check if `b` defines equality before failing over to comparing IDs. You can use that to define `__eq__` on the things you want to compare to the module much more easily than your current plan

Comment: OP, what's your end goal? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Modules do actually support [a couple of user-defined methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access), specifically `__getattr__` and `__dir__` for customizing the set of attributes exposed by the module (often used for lazy loading; you can report the imported names via `__dir__` without actually having imported them, and if someone tries to access those names, you can lazy load them in `__getattr__` on demand). With module subclasses, you can do truly terrible things. You just *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 7):

Modules are *instances* of the `module` class/type. `__eq__` (and most special methods) must be implemented on the type itself to be used (you can't assign to `__eq__` on an instance and have it acquire new comparison rules). Your module being an instance means it can't overload special methods (aside from some special cases specifically allowed for, like `__getattr__`); even if defined, `__eq__` will be ignored.

You could theoretically overload `__eq__` on some *other* user-defined type such that it would allow comparisons to `module` (even if the `module` is on the left hand side of the comparison, the `module` `__eq__` would return `NotImplemented` and then your other type would have it's own `__eq__` invoked to see if it knows how to compare to `module`s), but it's a terrible idea.

In short, this makes no sense. A module is equal to itself and nothing else; the idea that two independent modules should be treated as equivalent is bonkers on its face. I strongly suspect you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) and need to find a better way of solving your *real* problem rather than trying to make something terrible like this work.

---

Having said all that, it is *technically* possible to make module subclasses and replace the class of a module with that subclass. An [example is provided in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access) to use this to customize the stringified form of the module. That same technique could be used to retroactively overload the meaning of `__eq__` after the module has been imported. **Please never do this:**

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType

class WeirdCompareModule(ModuleType):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tuple):
            return self.my_tuple == other
        return NotImplemented

sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = WeirdCompareModule

my_tuple = 1, 2, 3

print(sys.modules[__name__] == (1, 2, 3))  # Prints True
```

Again, ***DO NOT DO THIS***, this is to illustrate something you *can* do, not something you *should* do.